# window.print(); load Issue

Tags: javascript, event-listener

I tried to print something using `window.print();`

It is working, but whenever I click my print button for the second time without reloading the page (which is unnecessary),
the window print will appear again even though I already click on close button.
After the code runs until `$('#main').show();` , it goes back to `window.print();` again.
And if I tried for the third time, it will reload the window print 3 times and so on.
I'm not sure how to terminate the query after I close the window for the first time.
I do not want the window to be reloaded again.

This is my code;

```
self.QrCode = ko.observable("../Content/img/qr-code (1).png");
self.GetQrCode = function (obj) {
    var ID = obj.Id;
    $.ajax({
        url: '/QC/GetQrCode',
        cache: false,
        type: 'GET',
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        data: { rejectsId: ID },
        success: function (rejectsId) {
            self.QrCode(rejectsId.QRCode);
            self.PrintQrCode();
        }
    });
}


self.PrintQrCode = function (obj) {
    $('#main').hide();
    $('#QrCodePrint').show();
    $("#test").on("load", function () {
        window.print();
        $('#QrCodePrint').hide();
        $('#main').show();
        return false; 
    });
}
```

Comment: What language are you using? JS?

Comment: Yes, and I'm using .Net MVC framework to run my code